# Why does my async function always return false to the wrapper function?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have an async function that triggers AWS Amplify to send a password reset code to a user.

```
export async function forgotPassword(username) {
  console.log('forgotPassword')
  return Auth.forgotPassword(username)
    .then(data => {
      console.log('aws reset password request success')
      console.log(data)
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log('error with call to AWS forgotPassword fncn')
    })
}
```

Here is a wrapper function that calls the function above...

```
  forgotPassword(email).then(success => {
    if (success) {
      console.log('successful forgot password action')
      Vue.prototype.$notification.success({
        message: 'Forgot password action success',
        description: 'You have successfully submitted a password refresh request!',
      })
    }
    if (!success) {
      console.log('failed forgot password action')
    }
  })
```

I know that the inner function runs successfully because my console log statement for debugging that method does indeed execute and print `'aws reset password request success'`.

However, my wrapper function always detects a failure in the aws function because I see that the wrapper function enters the !success clause. Why is this? I am guessing there is a syntax error with my async await code in the inner aws function

---

Update, based on the answers I've read so far, I updated my inner function as follows.

```
export async function forgotPassword(username) {
  console.log('forgotPassword')
  try {
    const data = await Auth.forgotPassword(username)
    console.log('aws password reset request success')
    console.log(data)
    return true
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('error with call to AWS forgotPassword fncn')
    notification.warning({
      message: error.code,
      description: error.message,
    })
  }
}
```

It appears to work properly.

Comment: There is no `return true` in your function (inside `.then`) so it returns nothing, i.e. `undefined`, which is falsy.

Comment: By the way you defined your function `async` but you don't make any use of it. It would be less confusing too, if you'd `await` the things instead of using `.then` (and use `try`/`catch` instead of `.catch`)

Comment: What would be an example of "making use of the async"?

Comment: Please elaborate on why the async/await syntax is less confusing. Would like to understand what you mean.

Comment: Rule of thumb: `async` without `await` is useless. Either use `async` with `await`, or don't use `async`.

Comment: Example: https://gist.github.com/CherryDT/ae088e976447dbf1d83d26e7c96715b5

Comment: @CherryDT I edited my question by adding my updated code to the end of the question. Now, is this the correct use of async/await with the try/catch clause or is it still not quite there yet?

Comment: Yep looks less confusing now, right? :) (also did you see my example I linked in my previous comment?)

Comment: Yes, it was helpful. I see your example returns false in the catch clause, which I left out. I guess it is better to explicitly return false for clarity.

Answer (score 3):

This is because your promise, returned by the first function, resolves to undefined. As you chain a `.then` to the initial promise, you should make sure to *return* the value *that* promise should resolve with:

```
    .then(data => {
      console.log('aws reset password request success')
      console.log(data)
      return data; // or: return true;
    })
```

Comment: This means the catch should return false, right? I'm still learning too  =)

Comment: Yes, if you want to. The default is `undefined`, which is "falsy", so `if (!success)` will work with that as well. NB: OP should maybe make that `if` an `else`.